# Python: Don't know how to get the total costs per warehouse for a FLP

Tags: python, model

I am working on a facility location problem. The model that I created in Python works, but I also want to get the total costs per warehouse and the total number of customers per warehouse. However I do not know how I can get this. Can someone help me? My model is similar to this problem: https://scipbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flp.html#weak-and-strong-formulations

In the code I retrieve the data from excel, instead of putting it in python. But the data, if you were to put in in python, is in there after a #-sign. Since I have to work with big files it is more convenient to retrieve the data from excel.
This is the code I have:

```py
import pandas as pd
from mip import Model, xsum, minimize, BINARY

Customer = list(range(1,6))
Warehouse = [1,2,3]


#Demand
#d = {1:80, 2:270, 3:250, 4:160, 5:180} --> D below is formatted the same as in here, only below it is extracted from excel

df = pd.read_excel('Demandd.xlsx') 
D = df.set_index('Customer').to_dict()['Demand']

#Operating costs
#O = {1: 1000, 2:1000, 3:1000} 
#Capacity
#C = {1:500, 2:500, 3:500}
#Here we have the same as described previously, below we have explained what indicates the operation costs and what indicates the capacity in WH.

#Two dimensions where dimension 1 is the capacity and dimension 2 is the Operation costs
# For capacity do: WH[j][0]
# For Operation costs do: WH[j][1]
df3 = pd.read_excel('Warehousedata.xlsx') 
WH = df3.set_index('WH').T.to_dict(orient='list') 

#Costmatrix
#c = {(1,1):4,  (1,2):6,  (1,3):9,
      #(2,1):5,  (2,2):4,  (2,3):7,
      #(3,1):6,  (3,2):3,  (3,3):4,
      #(4,1):8,  (4,2):5,  (4,3):3,
      #(5,1):10, (5,2):8,  (5,3):4,
      #}
#Also this costs matrix is retieved from excel below and can be indicated by DC[i][j]

df2 = pd.read_excel('/users/basroelofs/downloads/Costmatrix.xlsx') #import deliverycosts per customer per warehouse from excel
DC = df2.set_index('Customer').T.to_dict()



# We create an empty model to fill with variables and constraints
model = Model()

# We create empty variables x and y
x, y = {}, {}

# Filling the Decision variables (where j = warehouse j and i = customer i)
# y[j] is a binary value that says whether warehouse j is open or not
# x[i,j] is the value that says how much warehouse j serves to customer i.
# x[i,j] gives the possibility that one customers is served by multiple warehouses
for j in Warehouse:
    y[j] = model.add_var(var_type = BINARY, name="y(%s)"%j)
    for i in Customer:
        x[i,j] = model.add_var(var_type="C", name="x(%s,%s)"%(i,j))

# Now we create the constraints
# constraint 1:  Requires that each customer’s demand must be satisfied
for i in Customer:
    model.add_constr(xsum(x[i,j] for j in Warehouse) == D[i], "Demand(%s)"%i)

#Constraint 2: Capacity constraint --> capacity of WH[j] may not be exceeded
#CHECK this!!!!!!!!! IS WH good in LINE 45?
for j in Warehouse:
    model.add_constr(xsum(x[i,j] for i in Customer) <= WH[j][0]*y[j], "Capacity(%s)"%i)

#Constraint 3: Provide variable upperbound for variable x
for (i,j) in x:
    model.add_constr(x[i,j] <= D[i]*y[j], "Strong(%s,%s)"%(i,j))


# Objective function: Minimize the total costs
# Total costs = Sum(Delivery costs of customer i(for 1 visit) to warehouse j)
# + Sum(Operation costs of warehouse j * y[j])
model.objective = minimize(
    xsum(WH[j][1]*y[j] for j in Warehouse) + 
    xsum(DC[i][j] * x[i,j] for i in Customer for j in Warehouse))

#Optimize model
model.optimize()
EPS = 0.0001

#HERE I PRINT THE OUTCOMES I WANT, HOWEVER I ALSO NEED THE COSTS PER FACILTIY AND TOTAL CUSTOMERS PER FACILITY.
edges = [(i,j) for (i,j) in x if x[i,j].x > EPS]
facilities = [j for j in Warehouse if y[j].x > EPS]
print ("Optimal value=", (model.objective_value))
print ("Facilities at nodes:", facilities)
print ("Edges:", edges)
```

I tried the following:

```py
#For the # of customers, but this only give the number of edges:
customers=0
for j in Warehouse:
    for i in Customer:
        if x[i,j].x > EPS:
            customers = customers + 1


#For the total costs per facility/warehouse, but this does not give an answer:
som = 0
for j in Warehouse:
    som = som + (DC[i][j] for i in Customer)

print(som)
```

I use the MIP package. So what I need is:

1. The code to get the total costs per warehouse for the optimal value.
2. the code for the total # of customers per warehouse.

Thanks in advance people!

Comment: Far too broad. Can you really imagine someone sitting and writing a long answer which precisely answers your problem without you having to give more details? See [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Could you specify the problem with give us data and what you tried to so far.

Comment: @kağan hazal koçdemir, thanks for replying, I added the code, hope you can help me! :)

Comment: @PeterWood, I hope this is more specific and specific enough for you to help me. Thanks in advance! :)